# React Native Realm flexible sync progress screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

I have integrated realm flexible sync which download lots of data from realm database after user login and works fine but i want to show progress screen until all data are downloaded on first launch.

As per documentation i have integrated to get progress notification but it only notify when 100% downloaded which is not wise for our app as we want to show actual progress and once download complete start using the app.

Please find below code that i implemented for same as per documentation.

```
enum ProgressDirection {
    Download = 'download',
    Upload = 'upload',
}

enum ProgressMode {
    ReportIndefinitely = 'reportIndefinitely',
    ForCurrentlyOutstandingWork = 'forCurrentlyOutstandingWork',
}

const AppSync = () => {
    const app = useApp();
    const realm = useRealm();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (__DEV__) {
            Realm.App.Sync.setLogLevel(app, 'debug');
        }

        const progressNotificationCallback = (transferred, transferable) => {
            // Convert decimal to percent with no decimals
            // (e.g. 0.6666... -> 67)
            const percentTransferred = parseFloat((transferred / transferable).toFixed(2)) * 100;
            console.log('percentTransferred', percentTransferred);
        };

        // Listen for changes to connection state
        realm.syncSession?.addProgressNotification(
            ProgressDirection.Download,
            ProgressMode.ForCurrentlyOutstandingWork,
            progressNotificationCallback
        );
        // Remove the connection listener when component unmounts
        return () => {
            realm.syncSession?.removeProgressNotification(progressNotificationCallback);
            if (!realm.isClosed) realm.close();
        };
    }, []);

    ...
}
```

**Propblems:**

- `percentTransferred` log showed only when `percentTransferred` to 100%
- I am unable to implement progress screen which tells user that you have to wait as realm is syncing/download all the subscriptions data yet.
- Why progress screen is important because if I do not block users then app is very slow and laggy until all data are transferred.

My aim is to have progress screen until data get downloaded and once downloaded then render the app part only after it.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is with your code and include what troubleshooting you've done to narrow the issue? To do some basic troubleshooting, by add a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected, then post those results.

Comment: @Jay Please check I updated questions with problems key points and that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: Two things to note: at this time, [Flexible Sync progress notifications are not yet fully supported. When using Flexible Sync, downloads only report notifications after changes are integrated](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/sync-data/manage-sync-session/#check-upload---download-progress-for-a-sync-session). I think the documentation is a bit unclear but you'll note the example is for *uploads* - as mentioned, download progress is not fully supported yet. Did you trying changing `.ForCurrentlyOutstandingWork` to `.ReportIndefinitely` to see if that works better?

Comment: @Jay No that didn't worked but found one other way where i can get notified in promise resolve after realm download all changes using [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/js/latest/Realm.App.Sync.Session.html#downloadAllServerChanges)

Comment: Yeah - it's confirmed that In react, Flex Sync download progress is not fully supported.